# \app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk' Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t --user current

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola soy nuevo en android etoy haciendo mi primero aplicación y me salió un error al momento de ejecutarla. He hecho uso de fragments y de un drawerNavigation.

```
List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\nicon\Documents\AndroidStudio\TuristeandoApp\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: ''cmd package insta introducir el código aquí`ll-create -r -t --user current -S 6961423' returns error 'Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing:
android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
at android.util.ExceptionUtils.wrap(ExceptionUtils.java:34)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:596)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doCreateSession(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1347)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstallCreate(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:274)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:116)
at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:96)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:22550)
at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:573)
at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:473)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2683)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3669)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:497)
at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:416)
at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:431)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSessionInternal(PackageInstallerService.java:682)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:594)
... 10 more''
Retry
```

Me salió este error y ya limpie, reconstruí y sincronice el proyecto con las librerías gradle.
Como puedo solucionarlo es un error de debug.apk

Comment: Libera espacio para que no muestre el erro, el problema se debe a espacio.

Answer (score 0):

En Android 4 prueba a ir a Tools -> AVD Manager. Seleccionar en tu emulator device (con boton izquierdo) la opción STOP, y cuando termine, pulsa Cold Boot Now. Te explico algunos detalles del procedimiento, creo que es un problema de configuración del dispositivo virtual. Android Studio no es capaz de instalar la app y da este problema. Una vez reinicias la configuración del dispositivo con la opción Cold Boot Now, puedes instalar de nuevo sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

El problema aquì se indica en el LogCat:

[0] 'C:\Users\nicon\Documents\AndroidStudio\TuristeandoApp\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: ''cmd package insta introducir el código aquí`ll-create -r -t --user current -S 6961423' returns error 'Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing:
android.os.ParcelableException: **java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space**

Esto indica que tu dispositivo no cuenta con suficiente espacio para subir al dispositivo e instalar el apk, d**ebes eliminar algunos archivos o aplicaciones para liberar espacio**.

---

Precisamente es el problema que tengo actualmente en un dispositivo, tengo que liberar espacio para que instale la aplicaciòn:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]